# psr-4 autoloading issue in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, autoload, psr-4

Probably this has been answered several times before. I am trying to run autoloader through composer in Laravel.

I am getting this error while running  `composer dump-autoload`

```
Class App\Admin located in C:/xampp/htdocs/test/app\Models\Admin.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

I have checked the capitalisation in filesystem and looks ok to me.

Composer version is 2.0.14 which is latest.

Composer.json --

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ]
    },
```

Folder structure is:

```
<root_project>
 app
  Models
   Admin.php
   .....
 config
 public
 ...
```

`app/Models/Admin.php` :

```
namespace App;

use ....
use ....

class Admin extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
......
```

Please any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: try changing namespce from namespace App; to namespace App\Models;

Comment: @JohnLobo Thank you. I will try. In that case I will have to change all the files. Is there any way to do this through composer.json.

Comment: I use phpstorm. I will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace is wrong in your model, you're missing the sub-namespace of `Model` and have only the vendor namespace, which in the Laravel framework is set to `App`, pointing to the `app` folder as its base.

Changing your `Admin` models namespace to include the sub-namespace will fix your issue.

```php
namespace App\Models;

class Admin {}
```

This is because PSR-4 works off of file paths, with sub-namespaces being directories to travel through to reach the destined class and those directories must match the cases of the sub-namespaces. The same goes for class names, the file must match that of the class, for instance.

**IF** your base directory is `/src`, linked to the vendor namespace **Mitra**, a class in the root folder of `/src` will only have the namespace `Mitra`. **IF** you have a folder in the root; `/src/Models` **THEN** the namespace would be `Mitra\Models`.

The [specification](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) for PSR-4 is a rather short specification and is very well documented, I recommend reading it if you're having trouble understanding.